# Two tables connected via Primary Key

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have read about the use of @MapsId and @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotations, which sounds like a great options.  I have two tables (UserList and UserInformation) which have a child, parent relationship, respectively; both classes below are abbreviated to just include the relevant columns.  UserInformation's primary key value is always null and does not take the value of its parent column.

**User Class**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user_list")
public class UserList {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    // List of foreign keys connecting different entities
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    @MapsId("id")
    private UserInformation userInfo;
}
```

**UserInformation Class**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user_information")
public class UserInformation implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer userId;

    @OneToOne
    private UserList user;
}
```

I would prefer to not use an intermediary class if possible.  I'm not tied to MapsId or even this implementation if there is a better solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear to me, but I think you could improve the following in the modeling of the entity:

The @column annotation can only be omitted when the class parameter is called exactly the same as the database column, taking into account the table name nomenclature, could it be that the column is user_id ?, if so the id parameter should be :

```
@Id
@column(name="USER_ID")
private Integer userId;
```

In the user entity being id, it will match the DB ID field so the @column annotation is not necessary